# Tab Bar iPhone - Back button -> Open last active tab

Tags: iphone, xcode, back-button, tabbar

I'm working in Xcode to make an iPhone app. 
I've used the better part of my day to search for this answer without any luck.
(I'll explain as good as I can)

What I'm having trouble with is;

I have a initial view which is a tab bar controller, I've added three views (let's call them A, B, C). There's buttons on all of them, they do again go to other views (5, 6, 7).

However when I press a back button on one of the views it goes back to the initial view (A). Which is ok when the back button is pressed from the views which came from A, but it happens on all the views.

Ok, not very good explained..

Here:

A leads to 5, when pressing the back button on 5 it goes back to A
B leads to 6, when pressing the back button on 6 it goes back to A
C leads to 7, when pressing the back button on 7 it goes back to A

I want the buttons 6 and 7 go to B and C. (The last active tab bar item).
To put it very easily, I want the back button to lead to the last active tab bar view.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add code which you are using to push 5, 6 and 7

Comment: I'm using modal to push in storyboard.
Is is possible to just set which active view in the tab bar?
When I try to push modal back to the view I want, the tab bar disappears, and whenever I go back to the tab bar controller I get the first view, not the view  I want.

Comment: Still this can't be answered. When you present a modal, the view that presented it stays in the background. Ideally, if you presented a modal view from second bar, it should return to the same. But in your case, you are definitely doing something wrong when dismissing or when presenting the modal view.

Comment: Ok, thanks for super fast response! 
Check here for what I'm meaning: http://relatedsignals.com/Apps/TestModalApp/TestTabBar.zip
Download that project, and I've just made a new simple project, as you can see whenever I push modal back to the second view I'm not able to get the tab bar at the bottom and when I push modal to Tab Bar Controller it returns to FirstView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually making a technical mistake. You can present your modal views using storyboard GUI but to dismiss a modally presented you have to write action code.
You can use

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                                  completion:nil];
```

to dismiss your modally presented view.

Currently what you are doing (wrong) is that 
1) You have at the root you have a `UITabbarController` with two tabs. 
2) From second tab you present a modal view using a modal segue.
3) Now from this modal view, instead of dismissing it, you present another instance of your `tabbarController` and it shows first tab selected again.

So you have to create an `IBAction` and attach it with your 'Back to Tabbar view' button. Then call above code inside that `IBAction` as follows...

```
-(IBAction)backButtonTapped
{
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                                  completion:nil];
}
```

If still you are unable to understand, please go through [this excellent tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2).